# Can you illustrate how the weights in transformer model generated from a training sentence can be generalized to an unseen test sentence?

Tags: transformer, weights, generalization

Can you show how the weights in transformer model are generalizable?

Comment: I think the easiest way to understand generalisation of models is as follows. Imagine a cloud of 2d points that forms something that has roughly the shape of parabola. Now, you could create a function that goes exactly through all these points. However, this function is more likely to be wrong for new points than a function that just has a parabola shape. This is harder to explain than to show with a picture. So, I'd recommend you look online for a picture. In any case, I doubt you can do this easily for the transformer.

Comment: Could also please provide more info about your background? It seems you have little knowledge of ML. It's hard to satisfactorily answer any question in this way.